# Attemp at jquery refreshing a div and php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to refresh a div with jquery that loads the time which is generated with php.

I've read some of the articles on jquery that were already on here and tried using those to refresh my div, but I failed.

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>' . $title . '</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="styles/style.css" /> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="styles/layout.css" /> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="styles/' . $bodycss . '" /> 

</head> 
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function update() {
  $.get("'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'", function(data) {
    $("#time").html(data);
    window.setTimeout(update, 500);
  });
}
</script>



<div id="container">
 <header id="header" class="margin5"> 
    <div id="info">  <a href ="home.php"> <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Oppasweb" /> </a> </div> 
    <div id="time"><time datetime=' . getTimeForTag() . '>' . getTime() . '</time></div> 


         <div class="clear"></div> 

';
}
```

The javascript should refresh the div every .5 of a second, generating the new time, however it doesn't do that, the time stays static.

Comment: OMG! You echo the whole page!

Comment: Every 0.5 of a second as well.. I'd consider rethinking the whole strategy

Comment: usefull for debugging jquery and other javascript stuff is firebug in forefox. This can show your function step by step and shows where you have error ( like the answer below, a non closed function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your setInterval function is wrong (never closed).

you should not need it for that.

```
function update() {
  $.get("'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'", function(data) {
    $("#time").html(data);
    window.setTimeout(function() {update();}, 500);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  update();
});
```

moreover, with looping so often, you might want to id your call (with a i++), and append to the times to the div instead of replacing the full html. You might want to look for the difference between setTimeout and setInterval.

note: true, full html as string is bad practice. but for test purposes, it's not that important (imo)

Comment: How would you do it then (html part) :) ?